# MySQL table design to save multiple dates for training

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database-design

I am developing a web application to keep track of training dates.

For usual scenario, training dates are usually 10 June 2020 - 12 June 2020.
This would be straight forward for the database table column training_start_date & training_end_date

What if we have training dates like 10-12, 15, 16 June 2020?
How would I design the table for the training dates example above?

Thank you.

Comment: For a single day training you can have the training_start and training_end as same date with different times like training_start = '2020-06-16 08:00:00' and training_end = '2020-06-16 17:30:00'

Answer (score 1):

If a training may have multiple sessions, then I would recommend two tables.

```
create table trainings (
    training_id int primary key auto_increment,
    name        varchar(50)
);

create table sessions (
    session_id int primary key auto_increment,
    training_id int,
    date_start  datetime,
    date_end    datetime,
    constraint training_fk 
        foreign key (training_id) references trainings(training_id)
);
```

The parent table stores information on the training, while the child table contains one row per training session. I used `datetime`, since you might want to store a time component as well. Otherwise, you can use `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Classic master-detail design.

A table with the master information (training, event) and a table with detail information, referencing the master table with a foreign key.